# How to programatically create virtual IP Addresses in VB?

Tags: vb.net, network-programming, virtual-ip-address

What I want to do is use one PC to test an application on another on the same 19.2.168.X.X

I would like to make it seem like SOAP requests are coming from a variety of different PCs, just to make the applciations log file easier to read and I have been told that virtual IP Addresses are the way to go. So, how do I defien a range and then use them one by one in VB?  (I guss that this is effectively IP header spooging?)

Comment: It says it all, and yet, says nothing at all.

Comment: Why does this remind me of CSI? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175545/worst-technobabble-youve-ever-heard/175584#175584

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: "What have you come up with so far?" ... well, I posted here :-) and then I rephrased the question which hopefully makes it clearer what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want to do but I'd suggest first looking at the WMI class [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28VS.85%29.aspx) to see if you can do what you want with it.

If that class does not support it you might have to use [INetCfg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547694%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead, where I think you can change pretty much any network settings, but it's a bit more difficult to use. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/adapterlist.aspx)'s a codeproject article for using INetCfg from C# which might at least show you how to get started.

Comment: You'd want the EnableStatic() method. It accepts multiple IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a random IP address, generate 4 random numbers from 0 to 255 and glue some dots between them.

Comment: +1 O suppose I asked for that. Ok, I have made the question clearer (I hope)